# Javascript hide in php

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<?php 
    if( isset($_GET['message']) ) {
        $message = urldecode($_GET['message']);
        echo "<h2 id='mydivm'>". $message . "</h2>";
?>
    <script>
        setTimeout( function() {
            getElementById(mydivm).value='';
            // the alert is working
            alert("hello"); 
        }, 5000);
    </script>
<?php  
    } 
?>
```

I am trying to hide the $message after 5 seconds through `#mydivm`. However I can't get regular JavaScript to work or jQuery. Alert works when it is alone. I also have tinymic, but I don't think that is interfering. I have tried putting it outside the PHP

```
setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);

function fade_out() {
    $("#mydivm").fadeOut().empty();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#mydivm").delay(5000).fadeOut().empty();`?

Comment: Please look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). I bet there's an error message about `getElementById` not being a function.

Comment: To complete Juhana's statement: `document.getElementById()`

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820951/hide-div-after-a-few-seconds

Comment: $("#mydivm").delay(5000).fadeOut().empty(); This worked for some reason. and Juhana before I did have the error. Thanks guys

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820951/hide-div-after-a-few-seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getElementById is a method of the document. Also, you're not passing it a string. You need to change your code from this:

```
getElementById(mydivm).value='';
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById('mydivm').value='';
```

EDIT: 
Looking closer, setting the value attribute is not the correct way to do that either. You would need:

```
document.getElementById('mydivm').innerHTML='';
```

or better yet:

```
document.getElementById('mydivm').style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not where the error is coming from, but [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) is a function that belongs to the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document) object. Most likely, what's happening is that you're receiving a "undefined function getElementById" which you are not seeing. Use it this way:

```
document.getElementById('mydivm').value = '';
```