# auto accept or disable the pop up for cookie

Tags: session, cookies, popup, hide, integrate

I create a website wich one include articles integration and I have a problem with the pop up about cookies as a visitor, on my page the pop appear ont the article and hide almost all of it. Is it possible to auto-accept or disable that?

P.S: bottom of the page in the screenshoot  (sry for my english)

pop up for cookies:

[image]

Thank for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? [Hide div after time out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820954/6451874)

Set the timer for a few seconds :)

Another solution might be to check if it is the first entrance to this page and if not, set the `visibility` of the div to false.

Hope it helps, Good luck!