# How do I delay the removal of a div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code - it works if I remove the `.delay(2000)`, but what I am trying to do is remove it after 2 seconds.

```
 $('.back').on('click', function () {
      $(this).delay(2000).remove();
 });
```

Comment: use ``setTimeout()`` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820951/hide-div-after-a-few-seconds - this link might help

Answer (score 3):

The[`jquery delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) funciton works only for a *queue* of 'effects' and is not a replacement for [`javascirpt setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) which is more appropriate to be used here.

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.
>
> Source: [`jquery delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

See a demo below:

```js
$('.back').on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(() => {$(this).remove()}, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back">Some text here</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.back').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.back').remove();
    }, 2000);
});
```

You can see the demo here

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1z1x969f/)

Comment: But how will you make it dynamic. your code will work only on div with class back applied to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
You should make your execution wait
```

```js
var ele;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.back').on('click', function () {
   ele = this;
     setTimeout(function(){ 
         $(ele).remove();
     }, 1000);
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back" style="background-color:red; height:200px; width:200px;">
</div>
```

Comment: i try to use ``$(this)`` but not work

Comment: you won't get `this` inside `setTimeout`...

Comment: you should pass element to click function and same to settimeout function

Comment: @kukkuz  I have updated answer. please check it now and let us know it works for you or not

Comment: cool, it works now... :) +1

Comment: I think you have written the best solution @kukkuz. which requires no global or extra variables. thumb up for your solution.

Comment: @DonaldWu you should use the solution posted by kukkuz

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways through which you can hide class `.back`. If you are using `.remove()` method then delay won't work, it acts much similar to setting `.css('display','none')`, so you have to use `setTimeout()` and execute that. Whereas `delay` works fine with `.fadeOut()` as it animates element opacity and then hide that.

> .remove() -  Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself,
>   as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements
>   themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the
>   elements are removed.
>
> .fadeOut() - The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched
>   elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is
>   set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

```js
$('.back').on('click', function () {
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('.back').remove();
      },2000);
 });
```

```css
.back{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back">

</div>
```

```js
$('.back').on('click', function () {
      $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut();
 });
```

```css
.back{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back">

</div>
```

Comment: You faded out the element. I think it was not the question. fadeout does not remove the element and your another solution is static which may work for only one element. it requires to be dynamic.

Comment: @Maharshi OP wants to hide that div with delay of 2s after click. He didn't mention anything about dynamically.

Comment: but he said that he wants to remove element 'not hide'. logically its correct but technically we don't not fadeout.