# How to display a message in <p> tag for a few minutes and make it invisble in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a message in a

tag. I wanted to display it for few minutes and then blur it.

```
<p>Your message has been send successfully!!!</p>
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this ?

Comment: Try to use `setTimeout`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820951/hide-div-after-a-few-seconds

Comment: Use setTimeout() of jquery. and on timeout function you can do whatever you want

Comment: `$('p#selector').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');` //5 secondes

Answer (score 0):

Hello please check it:

```js
$("p").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test Message</p>
```