# Echo success or failure on the same page

Tags: php, ajax

This is my sign-up form.

```
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">   
      <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

  <form action="register.php" method="POST">

  <div class="top-row">
    <div class="field-wrap">
      <label>
        Username<span class="req">*</span>
      </label>
      <input name="username" type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
    </div>

    <div class="field-wrap">
      <label>
        E-mail<span class="req">*</span>
      </label>
      <input name="email" type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrap">
    <label>
      Password<span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    <input name="password" type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrap">
    <label>
      Repeat password<span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    <input name="rpassword" type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>
  </form>

</div>

<div id="login">   
  <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

  <form action="login.php" method="post">

    <div class="field-wrap">
    <label>
      Username<span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    <input name="username" type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrap">
    <label>
      Password<span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    <input name="password" type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>

  <p class="forgot"><a  href="forgot.php">Forgot Password?</a></p>

  <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Then the register.php

```
<?php
session_start();


$host= 'localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db='gameforum';


$conn=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

if ($password!==$rpassword) {
    echo "Passwords did not match, please try again!"
    $conn->close();
}
else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, Repeat_Password, email) 
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$rpassword', '$email')";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       $redirectUrl = 'index.php';

    echo '<script type="application/javascript">alert("Thank you for your registration! You may now log in with your account!"); window.location.href = "'.$redirectUrl.'";</script>';
}else{
    echo "Username or Email already exists!". mysql_error();
  }

$conn->close();
}


?>
```

The problem is that if the passwords do not match then the user comes to a blank page where it says that. I want the errormessage to pop up on the same page the user i signing up on. I do not know how to do that, any ideas?

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. You should use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: You could either redirect the user back to the page, storing the error message in a session and then outputting it if it exists. Or load the HTML form when the error occurs and add a new error message to it in the form of a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. One is to use sessions, the other one is to redirect user back to login page with something like signin.php?err=invalid_pass

of you do it with a session, you will need this code on top of your sign in page. It will print out error message if you set any in your signin page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['err']))
{
echo $_SESSION['err'];
unset($_SESSION['err'];
}
```

alternatively, you can add this code on top of your sign-in page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['err']))
echo $_REQUEST['err'];
```

You will also need to replace your `echo "Passwords did not match, please try again!"`

with this if you do sessions:

```
$_SESSION['err']="Passwords did not match, please try again!";
header("Location: signin.php");
```

and this if you do using the other method.

```
header("Location: signin.php?err=You_Goofed");
```

Comment: Do you know how to make the errormessage disappear after about 10 secs?

Comment: wrap your message in a div and include this javascript code. It Requires JQuery. But it is probably the simplest way.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820951/hide-div-after-a-few-seconds

Comment: Great! Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use ajax on your HTML page. When the user clicks on the form button, instead of submitting the form to the server, use ajax to send the data to the server. Then return the data from the server to the client.

Example:

```
$('#submit-btn').click(function(e){
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'register.php',
    data:{
      user:username,
      pw:password
    }
    }.done(function(data){
      if(data === false){
        alert("passwords don't match!");
      }
     });
});
```

In your PHP page, you will validate the passwords. If they don't match, echo false.